# Restrict Google Play Developer API to single app, and only alphas/betas

Tags: android, continuous-integration, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

In Google Play Console, Mike is only allowed to manage **testing track** releases, for a **single** app:

[image]

I commit new features to this app once or twice per day, and each time Mike must build an APK and upload it to the alpha track. Mike must do it within minutes of my commit, so that I get feedback from the many testers as soon as possible, ideally before I start working on another feature. Poor Mike.

So, I want continuous integration. Fortunately, there are many tools available that can notice the commit, build the APK and upload it to Play Store.

## Problem

When I connect the tool, I am told:

> Only the account owner can configure API access. Please contact them to update API settings

The account owner rightly refuses to grant me API access to stable releases, let alone other apps of the same account.

## Question

How can the account owner grant me API access for:

- Only a particular app,
- And only testing track releases (alpha/beta)?

Screenshots of the steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas Raoul, Did you find any solution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a registered API project, it gives you a new user for the API in the users screen. Just give the user the same permissions you give Mike. I would expect this to work.